# site enabled returns 404 error for newly added domains

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

an nginx 1.14.0 site configuration has a number of  domains pointing to a rails application.

```
server_name testing1.site.com testing2.site.com www.site.com testing1.site2.com testing2.site2.com www.site2.com;
```

Each of these domains is serving up properly, and have an associated certificate.

Adding these server names (on a single line)

```
server_name testing1.site.com testing2.site.com www.site.com testing1.site2.com testing2.site2.com www.site2.com 
iwantthis.com www.iwantthis.com;
```

then

```
sudo nginx -t
```

runs properly and

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

without hiccups. Then,  extending the certificate to the 2 new domains (via letsencrypt)  passes the test of having the domain specified in a server block. Pinging the domains confirms the local DNS server is synched up. 
Yet browser calls return a 404 error (the version of nginx shown is correct).

What is a possible source of this non routing and how can one test nginx's response for a specific domain request?

Comment: Have you eliminated browser cache as the source of the problem? Are there any corresponding access and error log entries?

Comment: bingo.  probably a very old cache was serving up an http URL (which I was NOT expecting, as letsencrypt has the option to re-direct all non-encrypted requests to https///